# HttpUtility.UrlEncode unexpected output

Tags: c#, .net, escaping, uri

Iam trying to encode a url, so that the HttpWebRequest is fine with characters like &.

So google bring me up to this:

```
url = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url);
```

But this makes the whole url unuseable. Iam getting Status-Error: Invalid Operation from Web-Server.

I got this url before iam using encoding:

```
http://jira-test.myServer.de/rest/api/2/search?jql=labels = "F&E"
```

After encoding i got this:

```
http%3a%2f%2fjira-test.brillux.de%2frest%2fapi%2f2%2fsearch%3fjql%3dlabels+%3d+%22F%26E%22
```

What iam doing wrong? In my opinion it shouldn't replace the // after http and so on... Or is there another way to handle this issue?

Info:

```
Uri.EscapeDataString();
```

gives me the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only be encoding the values of your query string, not the entire URI:

```
var uri = "http://jira-test.myServer.de/rest/api/2/search?jql=" +
          HttpUtility.UrlEncode("labels = \"F&E\"");

// Result: http://jira-test.myServer.de/rest/api/2/search?jql=labels+%3d+%22F%26E%22
```

The proper way to construct this:

```
// Construct query string using HttpValueCollection, which handles escaping:
var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
queryString.Add("jql", "labels = \"F&E\"");

// Combine base URI with query string through UriBuilder:
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder("http://jira-test.myServer.de/rest/api/2/search");
uriBuilder.Query = queryString.ToString();

// Get string representation:
string uri = uriBuilder.ToString();

// Result: http://jira-test.myserver.de:80/rest/api/2/search?jql=labels+%3d+%22F%26E%22
```